# PHP multiple image store record to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, php-5.3

I made a code for multiple image uploader, but just first image is stored to mysql table and both into path, some help?

This is my code:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){
        foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name){
            if($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0){
                $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];

                $ext = explode('.', $name);
                $ext = strtolower(end($ext));

                $file = md5_file($temp) . time() . '.' . $ext;              

                if(in_array($ext, $allowed) === true && move_uploaded_file($temp, "product_images/{$file}") === true){
                    $path = 'product_images';
                     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` (img_path, img_name) VALUES ('$path', '$file')");                                                  
                }else{
                    $errors[] = 'Format slike mora biti .jpg ili .png';
                }           
            }       
        }                       
}
```

Comment: Hi, try inserting `echo mysql_error();` directly after the query to see if there are any problems with your query. If you are lost there, please post the errors so that we can help!
On another note, use of the `mysql_` functions is discourages; PHP recommends to change everything to mysqli (see the [explanation on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for detail!

Comment: @JanD no errors, I will change mysql_ I already know thate, but thanks for advice

Comment: No errors is weird. Is is possible that something else is wrong? Maybe also put the following before query execution: `var_dump(in_array($ext, $allowed)); var_dump($file); ` ... Idea is to find out a) whether it is actually executed for every file, and b) if the values could mean trouble to MySQL.

Comment: @JanD maybe I should `implode(',', var)` ?

Comment: @JanD I get this with `var_dump` **bool(true) string(46) "64e5e39903c8b0c5608d8056fc6a09d81441634992.png" bool(true) string(46) "4bcae6e76e298e0f45ebf334bb5b9a671441634992.png"**

Comment: And you are sure that only the first actually reaches your database? Is it possible that you have a UNIQUE attribute on "path", which makes it impossible to add further files? (But if that were the case you should get MySQL errors...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89007/discussion-between-crovg-and-jan-d).